# How to construct mknod argument with device major and minor numbers

Tags: c, mknod

Lets say I want to create `/dev/cosole`. With the `mknod` command I do the following

```bash
  mknod -m 666 /dev/console c 5 1
```

If I want to do in in C code I have to do the following

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
static inline void (){
    mknod("/dev/console", 0600, __dev_t __dev);
}
```

How do I create the `__dev` argumment, documentation says

> Create a device file named PATH, with permission and special bits MODE and device number DEV (which can be constructed from major and minor device numbers with the `makedev' macro above).

I know character devices are of the type `S_IFCHR`. I know `/dev/console` has major `5` and minor `1`. How can I generate the __dev parameter with `makedev` macro as the documentation suggests. How do I account for whether its a block devices or a character device?

Comment: `makedev(5, 1)` ? _"How do I account for whether its a block devices or a character device?"_ - No need. If it's not, the `dev` parameter is ignored.

Comment: what if I want to make a block device?

Comment: How is that relevant to your question?

Comment: does mknod only create character devices?

Comment: `0600` looks wrong - that specifies a _regular file_.  For a character device, I'd expect `S_IFCHR | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR`  (and similar with `S_IFBLK` for a block device).

Comment: are you saying for `mknod (const char *__path, __mode_t __mode, __dev_t __dev)` `__mode` is for the device type not the file permission?

Comment: *The mode argument specifies both the file mode to use and the type of node to be created.* So it's both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of `mknod()` is created using the `makedev()` macro, and holds the major and minor device numbers. The **type** of device - if it's a character or block device (The argument is ignored for other file types), in included in the second argument, which is a combination of the permission bits bitwise-or'ed with the type of the file - `S_IFCHR` for character devices, or `S_IFBLK` for block devices (It can also be used to make regular files, FIFOs and unix sockets, but those are more commonly created using other functions like `open()`, `creat()`, `mkfifo()`, `bind()`, etc.). So you'd do something like

```c
int status = mknod("/path/to/my/new/console", S_IFCHR | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, makedev(5, 1));
```